# Debug Mode timeout Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I try to start my Tomcat in debug mode but it throws the following error:

> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor

I even tried to update the timeout time but it still gets timed out. But, when I try to start the tomcat (in non debugging mode) it starts normally. Any idea what might be causing problem?

Comment: Where did you update the timeout?

Comment: tomcat server configuration using eclipse but to no avail.

Comment: did you check how much time it is taking while in non-Debug mode?

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic. It regards both bullet points 3 and 4: it regards software tools commonly used by programmers and it regards a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Figured out the reason. If we have too many breakpoints the debug mode strangely takes too much time to start. Disable all the breakpoints and start in debug mode, when started enable the breakpoints as needed.

Comment: @Global Warrior: Thanks, worked for me too, despite only having five breakpoints. Incredible bug. And I don't understand why this question is closed.

Comment: I had only two breakpoints but they were "Java Exception Breakpoints". Visitors be warned. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, too, but I had only 4 breakpoints, and have had many more than that in the past.  *shrug*

Comment: Well, I set up my workspace yesterday and since then I've made three breakpoints. Once I removed them all, it suddenly started to work. So maybe the problem is not related to the number of breakpoints but to breakpoints in general.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be waiting for you to connect?

The docs say to type:

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n

but if you typed suspend=y, it would wait forever eventually timing out.